# Google Earth Engine coordinate system of point sample

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, georeferencing, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am taking a random sample of points from a landcover raster in GEE. I then overlay those points with other rasters and extract pixel values (to be used for regression analysis). I want to know what coordinate system the returned sampled points will be in, and whether I need to specify that crs when overlaying the sample featureCollection with future rasters. For example, in the code example below, what is the crs of the lat-lons returned in point_sample, and how should that crs be enforced when overlaying the points with the new elevation raster?

Based on the documentation of `ee.Image.sample`, the projection of the image's first band is used in sampling (unless a different projection is specified). I am guessing that this means that the lat-lons returned will be in the crs of my gap raster (EPSG:5070) and that when overlaying the points with the elevation raster, I must specify that as my projection, otherwise, the points will not be correctly interpreted. Is that a correct statement?

```
# Extract 100 random points from the landcover raster
gap = ee.Image('USGS/GAP/CONUS/2011');
point_sample = gap.sample(
  scale= 30,
  numPixels= 100,
  seed= 10,
  geometries= True
)

# Overlay the points with a new ratser and extract the pixel values
elevation = ee.Image('USGS/NED')
def extract(point):    
    elev_val = elevation.reduceRegion(
          reducer= ee.Reducer.first(),
          geometry= point.geometry(),
          )
    return point.set(elev_val)

point_sample.map(extract)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is about 1/2 correct, but ultimately, the answer is no, you don't need to specify a crs.

When you sample the landcover this way, you get **values** sampled from the original raster using its CRS (apparently EPSG:5070 in this case), however the coordinates returned with each point, when geometries is true, are just the corresponding lat/lon.  There aren't in any projection; they're just latitude and longitude.  Technically, it's the location of the center of the 30m EPSG:5070 pixel, but the lat/lon values are still just a location on the WGS84 sphere, not **in** any specific projection.

You can use those coordinates to sample any other raster in whatever CRS it is in; Earth Engine will do the appropriate conversion automatically and you don't need to specify a CRS in order to use them.